# Permission denied in "make qemu" in wtakuo/xv6-env docker image

Tags: linux, docker, operating-system, xv6

I have an image from `https://hub.docker.com/r/wtakuo/xv6-env`. I pull it with `docker pull wtakuo/xv6-env` and run it with:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/home/xv6/xv6-riscv wtakuo/xv6-env
```

After container created and run image on its, I run `make qemu` but I get this error:

```
mkfs/mkfs fs.img README user/_cat user/_echo user/_forktest user/_grep user/_init user/_kill user/_ln user/_ls user/_mkdir user/_rm user/_sh user/_stressfs user/_usertests user/_grind user/_wc user/_zombie 
fs.img: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:137: fs.img] Error 1
```

I don't know what should be do to fix it.
this is my directory content (with `ll` command):

```
drwxrwxr-x 8 root root 4096 Nov  1 16:30 .git/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xv6  xv6  1174 Nov  1 16:27 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xv6  xv6  4709 Nov  1 16:27 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 2305 Nov  1 16:24 README
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xv6  xv6    17 Nov  1 16:30 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 2 xv6  xv6  4096 Nov  4 17:57 kernel/
drwxrwxr-x 2 xv6  xv6  4096 Nov  4 17:57 mkfs/
drwxrwxr-x 2 xv6  xv6  4096 Nov  4 17:57 user/
```

I googled for this but not found effectively answer.
I tried

```
sudo chown -R user1:user1 *
```

but show this error: `fs.img: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, we must use from `sudo` command.

our user is `xv6` and the password is also the same.

after use from it, we see this output:

```
xv6 kernel is booting

hart 1 starting
hart 2 starting
init: starting sh
```